# popup text on mouse hover over svg element not removing when U put mouse out

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover over the svg element, the div pops up, but when I remove the mouse the text is still in the box.

I tried to change mouseout to mouseremove but nothing changed

```js
const svgElement = document.querySelector('.svaly');

svgElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  const popup = document.createElement('div');
  popup.classList.add('popup');
  popup.innerHTML = 'This is a pop-up comment';

  document.body.appendChild(popup);
});

svgElement.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
  document.body.removeChild(popup);
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svaly" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
<div class="popup"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting the popups.

Also the svg is not round but square so you need to look at the circle element

NOTE: You need more code to allow the popup to stay when the popup itself is moused over

```js
const svgElement = document.getElementById('circle');

svgElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  const popup = document.createElement('div');
  popup.classList.add('popup');
  popup.innerHTML = 'This is a pop-up comment';
  document.body.appendChild(popup);
});

svgElement.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { 
  const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
  popup.remove()
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svaly" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Here is a simpler version

note the pointer-events: none;  - if you need to click the popup then that will not work

```js
const svgElement = document.getElementById('circle');
const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
svgElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => popup.hidden = false);
svgElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => popup.hidden = true);
```

```css
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svaly" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
<div id="popup" hidden>This is a pop-up comment</div>
```

Comment: it doesnt work on hover property, it appears for like a milisecond and immidiately dissapears

Comment: Works for me as long as I hover somewhere else than where the popup is

Comment: I changed the second version to use pointer-events: none; and mouseenter/mouseleave